# Refresh tab page on tab selection in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

How can I refresh a tab page on tab selection in ionic 3?

Scenario: When a tab is selected I want that page to be reloaded so the data from the server can be updated.

**My tab.ts**

```
export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = DashboardPage;
  tab2Root = AboutPage;
  tab3Root = ContactPage;
  tab4Root = CashoutPage;
  tab5Root = ProfilePage;
  

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

**What I tried:**

```
 ionTabsDidChange(refresher){
    this.ionViewDidLoad();
    refresher.complete();
    console.log("Tab clicked");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the event that triggers `ionTabsDidChange` is not firing up, you can try using `(ionTabsDidChange)=""` on you  html tag like this:

`<ion-tabs (ionTabsDidChange)="ionTabsDidChange($event)" > </ion-tabs>`

[Reference](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/19665)